Referencing DOM objects directly by their IDs is automatically enabled - is it a good practice?
I was today years old when I learned that every HTML element added to the DOM and given an id is automatically added to the window object using the name provided in the id.
For example, <input type="text" id="txtName"> automatically creates the variable window.txtName which points to this HTML element, in most/all(?) browsers. (I don't even know how to check browser support for this feature!)
ChatGPT insists it is bad practice to reference HTML elements using these variables.  However, it also states that this functionality is supported in all modern browsers and is not deprecated.
This being the case, why not use this feature?  It makes code much clearer and more concise. Consider:
document.getElementById("txtName").value = "Hello"
vs
txtName.value = "Hello"
Obviously there could be naming conflicts with other variables, but if these variables are created automatically and there's nothing we can do about it, simply using good naming practices and proper scoping should avoid conflicts.
Please help me understand why this is a bad practice/what I am missing, because as of now, I think it looks very appealing.
Also, what is the "official" name of this feature?

Related: Do DOM tree elements with IDs become global properties? | Is there a spec that the id of elements should be made global variable?

you can use a furniture instead of your cars chair, that also may help you more convenience but IT IS NOT STANDARD under any protocol or convention, since that is not standard under any protocol if for example someone like me wants to make a new browser, your code won't work in that, there should be more conflicts with some occasions like strict mode or even well-known browsers like modes of browsing, thats why we need standards and protocols, anyway i also think that why we shouldn't use of this, you can apply for an suggestion on whatwg or w3...
